# Automated removal of dangles / loose ends in line with QGIS?

Tags: qgis, line

Here's what I want to do:

[image]

The original line is a dissolved osm extract of ways, which I want to simplify to one continous line without dangles / loose ends (red x's in picture).

I found the network generalization tool in GRASS, but possibly there is a QGIS way ro remove loose ends.

If there is no QGIS-only approach to do it, what would the parameterization in GRASS would have to look like to yield the desired result?

Comment: You could route from the start to the end. Are you looking for the longest possible line as a result? e.g. on the left side: should the algorithm chose the longer "arm"?

Comment: @underdark, exactly!

Comment: There is an option in _v.clean_ called **rmdangle** (from GRASS) which should remove dangles if the threshold is < 0. You can adjust the threshold if you use _v.clean.advanced_ if dangles remain, although I have never used this option so cannot confirm if it will work.

Comment: I found the Road Graph Plugin which will route through the network findung the shortest path, which yields exactly the continous line that I want - @underdark, if you put the routing-approach as an answer, I'll check it!

Comment: @Joseph, thanks for pinpointing the GRASS tool rmdangle, I'll also will have a look at it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a (somewhat manual) approach is fine for you, you could route from the start to the end point e.g. using the Road Graph plugin.

Otherwise, you'd have to find a way to automatically detect where the start and end points are.