# Removing 'tails' from line features?

Tags: qgis, line, voronoi-thiessen

I have a set of polygon centerlines created using voronoi polygons. The method seems to work well for what I want to accomplish, but these 'tail' remnants are throwing off successive analysis (attached an image). Is there a way to remove them from the lines automatically? Note: I would prefer if this could be done with QGIS tools, but can create a python script if necessary.

I would be open to switching methods for obtaining polygon centerlines. I know there is a 'Polygon Centerline' tool in ArcMap, but I don't have access to it.

[image: "Tails" on line features]

Comment: Are these "tails", topologically speaking, a single line segment or do they go out and back again? Because if your diagram above is a single feature and the tails are single segments of a multi-line feature then converting multi-parts to features then removing small features should do the job. Got sample data?

Comment: For clarification, are they like ____/\\____ ("out and back") or ____|____ (true topological branches)

Comment: Hi Spacedman, the 'tails' were true topological branches (___I___). I determined that they were a result of jagged source polygons, creating messy voronoi polygons (that made spatial queries impossible). All solved now, but thanks for your assistance!

Comment: @GIS_Canuck - Just an FYI, you should add the '@' symbol before someone's name so that they can receive a notification in their inbox. Otherwise they won't receive your message ;)

Comment: Cheers @Joseph, appreciate it!

Answer (score 4):

I ended up simplifying the source polygons that were used to create the voronoi polygons, making it a much cleaner surface to work with. This eliminated the dangles, as there were no lines remaining that couldn't be selected through a spatial query. Thanks to all who replied!

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer by clicking the green-faded tick on the left-hand side, this let's everyone know your problem has been solved :)

Answer (score 3):

Have you seen this question:

[Automated removal of dangles / loose ends in line with QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118201/automated-removal-of-dangles-loose-ends-in-line-with-qgis)

In ArcGIS you could use [Delete Dangles](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/production-mapping-toolbox/delete-dangles.htm) tool.

> Removes lines that are shorter than the specified length and do not
>   connect to other features on both ends.

Comment: Thanks artwork21. I hadn't seen that question, but it doesn't necessarily help. 

I ended up simplifying the source polygons that were used to create the voronoi polygons, making it a much cleaner surface to work with. No more loose ends!

Comment: @GIS_Canuck - You should post your _comment_ as an **answer** =)