# Cleaning up layer by deleting features with only one overlapping vertex in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, expression

After applying [`r.thin`](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass77/manuals/r.thin.html) and then [`r.to.vect`](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass77/manuals/r.to.vect.html) to a raster image the resulting vector layer contains hundreds of small *"branches"* that are not supposed to be there:

[image: Vector layer showing unwanted branches]

I've tried selecting and deleting these mini branches using a `$length` field in the layer's attribute table but that also deleted short segments in the main contours I want to keep.

A solution would be to identify all short paths where `nodes_to_points = 2` and `number of intersecting vertices = 1` as this would leave out the paths that are part of the contour (and therefore have 2 intersecting vertices).

Does anybody know how to write this as an expression in the Field Calculator or can think of a better way to remove my unwanted artefacts?

Comment: Try this [`v.clean`](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass77/manuals/v.clean.html) with `rmdangle` parameter

Comment: Thanks! That worked brilliantly. It's my first time posting here so how do I give you credit for your answer or label my question as "solved'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve the result that you are striving for with GRASS toolset [`v.clean`](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass77/manuals/v.clean.html) for cleaning topology of a vector element. Probably, you will need to deploy `rmdangle` option.

> `rmdangle`: remove dangles, threshold ignored if < 0

Important to set up `Threshold` and `snap tolerance` parameters.

Check the following references for more details:

- [Removing 'tails' from line features?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/218559/removing-tails-from-line-features?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Deleting lines in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/181852/deleting-lines-in-qgis)
- [Automated removal of dangles / loose ends in line with QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118201/automated-removal-of-dangles-loose-ends-in-line-with-qgis?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 1):

> Tested on QGIS 2.18 and QGIS 3.4

Additionally, I can suggest using a `"Virtual Layer"` through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...`.

Let's assume we have the following layer `"line"` with its Attribute table, see image below.

[image: input1]

With the following query, it is possible to clean up the line out of *"tails"/"dangles"*.

```sql
SELECT l1.*
FROM line AS l1, line AS l2
WHERE st_intersects(start_point(l1.geometry),end_point(l2.geometry))
OR st_intersects(start_point(l2.geometry),end_point(l1.geometry))
GROUP BY l1.id
```

The output Virtual Layer with its Attribute table will look as following

[image: output1]

---

> Mind the fact that previous example will erase only *"tails"/"dangles"* that are not connected to the starting/points of line features. Additionally, you will need to adjust the query accordingly.

Let's assume we have the following layer `"line"` with its Attribute table, see image below.

[image: input1]

With the following query, it is possible to clean up the line out of *"tails"/"dangles"* that own two vertices.

```sql
SELECT l1.*
FROM line AS l1, line AS l2
WHERE ST_NumPoints(l1.geometry) > 2
AND (st_intersects(start_point(l1.geometry),end_point(l2.geometry))
OR st_intersects(start_point(l2.geometry),end_point(l1.geometry)))
GROUP BY l1.id
```

The output Virtual Layer with its Attribute table will look as following

[image: output2]